# Different between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to take the different values between `table2` to `table1` (I should compare `table2` to `table1`).
I tried with `Join` but unfortunately it doesn't work for me (or simply I don't know what to write).

table1:

```
id
---
1
2
```

table2:

```
id
---
4
5
7
2
3
1
```

Result should be - 4, 5, 7, 3

Comment: Your previous questions make me think that you're using MySql.. is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Curt's answer is correct anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id
FROM [TableB]
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM [TableA] WHERE [TableA].id=[TableB].id)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t2.ID
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way:

```
SELECT id
FROM table2
WHERE id NOT IN
      ( SELECT id
        FROM table1
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `except`. See mention of `except` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx).

Comment: Why do you think Luis is using SQL Server?